# AddressBook ABPerson Twitter Social Profile

Tags: ios, addressbook

Have you ever tried to get data fields from the address book and ran into the wonderful world of ABPerson reference only to find it reads like the blueprints to a space rocket?

I've gotten so far but I still need help getting just the Twitter username key & value:

```
//I tried this but I can't seem to get the if statement to work
ABMutableMultiValueRef socialMulti = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonSocialProfileProperty);
NSMutableDictionary *mySocialDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:ABMultiValueGetCount(socialMulti)];
NSLog(@"entering social dict of count %ld", ABMultiValueGetCount(socialMulti));
for (CFIndex i = 0; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(socialMulti); i++) { 
    CFStringRef socialLabel = ABAddressBookCopyLocalizedLabel(ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(socialMulti, i));
    CFStringRef social = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(socialMulti, i); 
    if ([(__bridge NSString*)socialLabel isEqualToString:@"twitter"]) {
        NSLog(@"we got a twitter");
    }
    [mySocialDict setObject:(__bridge NSString*)social forKey:(__bridge NSString*)socialLabel];
    NSLog(@"social is %@",social);

    CFRelease(social);
    CFRelease(socialLabel);
```

}

I'm actually just interested in the twitter username.  I know I could get it from the dictionary I created but I want to get it directly.  I plan to eliminate the NSDictionary step anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an excerpt from my code. Replace your var names as necessary.

```
ABMultiValueRef socialMulti = ABRecordCopyValue(recordRef, kABPersonSocialProfileProperty);
NSMutableArray* twitterHandlesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:ABMultiValueGetCount(socialMulti)];
for (CFIndex i = 0; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(socialMulti); i++) {
    NSDictionary* social = (__bridge NSDictionary*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(socialMulti, i);
    if ([social[@"service"] isEqualToString:(__bridge NSString*)kABPersonSocialProfileServiceTwitter]) {
        NSString* username = (NSString*)social[@"username"];
        NSLog(@"we got a twitter. username is %@", username);

        [twitterHandlesArray addObject:[[username conditionedAsTwitterHandle] SHA2Digest]];
    }
}
```

Comment: I get "array subscript is not an integer" at both the if social service is EqualtoString and nsstring username lines.  Then I get a No visible interface for NSString declares the selector conditionedAsTwitterHandler.